# How to pass `self` implicitly to function when calling with square brakets?

Tags: lua

If you call a function like this:

```
some_table:method (a, b)
```

...then the function will receive `some_table` as its first argument, and many functions dub this `self` (or use a notation `function Some_Class:method (a, b)` where it's done for them), and assume it is an object that has this function as a method.

However, if the name of the method to be called isn't known at implementation time, you need to use square brackets to access a function, like this:

```
some_table [method_name] (a, b)
```

...and in that case the respective method won't get `some_table` as `self`. Of course we can pass it manually, like this:

```
some_table [method_name] (method_name, a, b)
```

But that's a bit inconvenient (especially if `some_table` is actually an expression like `some_other_table [member].children [4]:getHelperTable().helper` (a contrived example). Is there some sort of syntactic sugar or a magic trick to pass `self` implicitly in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.

The only syntactic sugar of this form is `foo:bar(...)` which translates into `foo.bar(foo, ...)` - anything else you just have to provide the first argument manually.

You could of course just write a wrapper function:

```
function selfcall(obj, method, ...)
    obj[method](obj, ...)
end
```

Then your example becomes something like...

```
selfcall(some_other_table[member].children[4]:getHelperTable().helper,
         method_name)
```

Of course, another option is to just use a local to store the expression:

```
local foo = some_other_table[member].children[4]:getHelperTable().helper
foo[method_name](foo)
```